# Is there flair for Careers.SO?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, flair

Are there any image badges like those on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/profile-badges) for Careers.SO?

> [image: Linkedin "Flair"]

I would like to add a nice image to my website profile.

Comment: I just cooked up http://jsfiddle.net/ANFuG/. Feel free to use that...

Answer (score 6):

**Not that I know of...**

With that being said, the following code should do the trick:

```
<button>[![][1]][2]</button>​
```

You'll have to stick your profile URL instead of the `href="http://stackoverflow.com"` URL. Then you'll have a big:

[image]​

That links to your account profile. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just found this undocumented(?) png flair:

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/11618.png
```

which renders to

[image: powtac on stackoverflow]

Comment: It got nothing to do with careers, it's the global flair and "documented" in your network profile.